# Prevent Rebuilding Previous Page for Using Same Bottom Navigation in separate page In flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basiacally I need to know how to prevent rebuild of previous page while loading current page.
Or I need to know current Page State

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved the issue , checking current route

**ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent**

Feel free to give your solution.

Thanks